# Pass a global variable into a function's scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to override `console.log` for an individual function, without affecting the global variable outside of the function. Essentially I'd like `myFunction()` to invoke a different `console.log` than the rest of the application.

Note that I **cannot** modify the body of the function, which is what is making this tricky for me.

Also note that `myFunction` in the example below is asynchronous (an express router), so I cannot simply restore the original `console.log` after invoking the function.

```
__originalConsole = console.log.bind(console);
invokeFunction() {
  const customConsole = (...args) => {
      args.unshift(`custom_behavior`);
      __originalConsole.apply(this, args);
  }
  myFunction() // <-- needs to access `customConsole` as though it were `console.log`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re almost there - all that’s left is to overwrite `console.log` and reset it after the function call.

If your custom logger needs to access `console.log`, you’ll need to use `bind()` to attach `originalConsole` as a parameter of `customConsole`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('Hello, world!');
}

function customConsole(log, ...args) {
  log('CUSTOM', ...args);
}

function invokeFunction() {
  // Store a reference to the original console.log
  const originalConsole = console.log;

  // Overwrite console.log with custom logging function
  console.log = customConsole.bind(null, originalConsole);

  // Make function call
  myFunction();

  // Restore console.log for future use
  console.log = originalConsole;
}

invokeFunction();
```

Comment: This works, but unfortunately `myFunction` is asynchronous, so logs happening in other places before the restoration in your answer also have the custom behavior. `myFunction` in this case is an express route handler.